# how to redirect and hide/unhide directories using java?

Tags: java

I have created a group of some users. Now I don't want these users to access the c:/ drive, so I need to hide the c:/ drive and unhide it when not required. I also want to redirect the entire d:/ drive to the network drive, so, how can both these things i.e. hiding/unhiding the local directory and re-direct drive on to a network drive be done using java?
thanku :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do that...

BUT...

If this is in the context of an application alone, and you can use Java 7 or more, you do have the option of providing your own default `FileSystemProvider`.

This can be quite some work, however...

Comment: ok will try using a FileSystemProvider. can you provide me some hints as to how do I proceed?